# LARAVEL5 Custom login

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working in application which requires a custom login.

I've to follow this flow.

1. User will enter login page.
2. User submit login page.
3. Application will check if the user is in database
   3.1 (If user not in database | it will send a request to a third-party and check if login succeeded)
   3.2 If user is in database verify password.

Now i've done class for the third-party and the code will work as this

```
$third = new Libraries\ThirdParty();
$third->login($username, $password);
```

`$third->login` will return true if login succeeded.

Now the question is how to link this logic. with the laravel pre-defined function `Auth::check()`

Comment: which things you think has better solution than default auth with laravel?

Comment: @SafoorSafdar Well, Auth in laravel came out-of-the-box. This type of auth usually used. but still if you need any extra things or re-logic things. you need to do it. In my case "better solution" i think as Carlos said.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you install laravel, it comes with a default login, that uses a trait:

```
class AuthController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard  $auth
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar  $registrar
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth, Registrar $registrar)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->registrar = $registrar;

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

}
```

this class use the trait for login stored in: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php`

you can overwrite the methods from this class to put your own logic, for example in the class `AuthController` you can define a new:

```
function postLogin(){
   //your new logic for login
}
```

and it gonna respect your function instead the trait funcion.
anyway, the logic behind the `postLogin` from `auth trait` is:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        { //this if validate if the user is on the database line 1
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            //this redirect if user is the db line 2
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
                    ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
                    ->withErrors([
                        'email' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                    ]);
          //redirect again to login view with some errors line 3
    }
```

you can do two things:

1. edit the trait itself **(bad practice)** to put your own logic
2. define your own `postLogin` function in `AuthController` and copy the logic but edit it with your own custom logic.

**Edit**
to be more conrete with your points:

1. User will enter login page: you can use the default login page that laravel gives you, or you can overwrite `getLogin` function and redircet to your own view.
2. User submit login page: the form action needs to be: `{{ url('/auth/login') }}` or whatever route you put to `postLogin()`
3. Application will check if the user is in database: in the code line 1

   3.1 (If user not in database | it will send a request to a third-party and check if login succeeded): in the code line 3

3.2 If user is in database verify password: in the code line 2

Comment: do you wanna know if is an user logged in before load the loggin page?

Answer (score 0):

```
custom login 100% wroking without auth    

use Hash;

$data->password = Hash::make(($request->password)); Encript Password

public function requestEmployee(Request $request)
{
    if ($data = AddEmployee::where('name', $request->name)->first()) {
        $pass = Hash::check($request->password, $data->password);
        if ($pass) {
            echo "sucess";
        } else {
            echo "Password Not Valid";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Username Not Valid" . "<br>";
    }
}
```