# Laravel How to store extra data/value in session Laravel

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.1

I'm using default auth() in laravel login (email & password)
Now i try to take input from the user in text field like (Age or City)

Now i want to store (Age/City) in my session.

Help me

Comment: why store age in session? why not just extract it from auth user when needed?

Comment: Is there any way to store my text field value in session when i click on login button or get login successfully. ?

Comment: i have posted an answer to do it right way

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#basic-usage) helper:

```
session('age', 18); // saves age into session

$age = session('age')`; // gets age from session
```

**Update**

If you want to save Age and City after user registration, you should store this data in a DB, not in a session. You can add some fileds in `create` method of `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php`

Comment: But where do i have to write. I'm new in laravel

Comment: Wherever you want: controller's method, Blade template, middleware etc. It depends on what are you trying to do.

Comment: Alexey i need this value when auth value get and check for login. 
Which file in laravel to check user and password is match or not ?

Comment: @KevalGarala, please look at **update** section of my answer

Comment: Is there any way to store my text field value in session when i click on login button or get login successfully. ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`Session::put('key', 'value');`

To get key from Session use

```
Session::get('key');
```

You can use the `session()` helper function as **[@Alexey Mezenin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin)** answer.

**[Laravel Session Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session)**

Comment: But where do i have to write. I'm new in laravel

Comment: Have you added the age/city in your login form?

Comment: Yes i added this in my login form

Comment: You need to override ```postLogin()``` in ```AuthController``` refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656113/laravel5-custom-login  it may help you.

Comment: No i don't want to do that.
Is there any way to store my text field value in session when i click on login button or get login successfully. ?

Comment: ```AuthController``` is responsible for ```Authentication``` you need to do it there, Or. Add if statement in everysingle controller to check if user ```Authenticated``` **I don't recommend this way at all**

Comment: Where in AuthController ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me enlighten you. if you want to store it in session do it this way.

```
session('country', $user->country); // save
$country = session('country')`; // retrieve
```

**But that is not the way we do in Laravel like frameworks, it uses models**

once the user is authenticated each time when we refresh the page, application looks for the database users table whether the user exists in the table. the authenticated user model is a user model too. so through it we can extract any column. first thing is add extra fields to the User class(Model)  $fillable array.
 so it would look something like this.

**User.php**

```
protected $fillable = ['username', 'password', 'remember_token', 'country'];
```

so after simply logging in with user name and password in anywhere just use Request class or Auth facade. Facades are not too recommended so here for your good as a new one i would just say how to use Request. Suppose you want to retrieve your  Authenticated user country inside TestController.php here is how it could be used in the methods.

**TestController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function testMethod(Request $request)
{
   $someCountry = $request->user()->country; //gets the logged in user country
   dd($someCountry); //dd is die and dump, could be used for debugging purposes like var_dump() method
}
```

Comment: It's very true.

But i don't want to store country in database.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Request**

public function ControllerName (Request $request){

```
   $request->session()->put('session_age', $age);

}
```

**Get session_age**

```
$get_session_age = $request->session()->get('session_age');
```

**Using Session**

```
   public function ControllerName (){

       Session::put('age',$age);

    }
```

**Get the session**

```
$session_age = Session::get('age');
```

Don't forget to define Session or Request in your controller!!!

```
use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with session in your controller you need to include session first in your controller

```
use Session;
```

After that for store data in session. There is several ways to do it. I prefer this one (in controller)

```
session()->put('key',$value);
```

To display session data in your View you can do it like this

```
@if(Session::has('key'))
I'v got session data
@else
I don't have session data
@endif
```

To get session data in your Controller you can do it like this

```
session()->get('key')
//or
session()->get('key','defaul_value_if_session_dont_exist')
```

When you are done with your data in session you can delete it like this (in controller)

```
session()->forget('key');
```

All this basic usage of session is well documented in official Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session).

Hope it helps you