# How to send values to session ? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a cart. For now I can add products to session and view them in my cart. This is my CartController functions:

`Add` function:

```
public function add(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->session()->push('cart', $id);
    flash()->success('Prekė sėkmingai pridėtą į krepšelį.');
    return redirect('/prekes');
}
```

`Show` function:

```
public function show()
{

    $products = session('cart');
    $products = Product::find($products);
    return view('cart.show', compact('products'));
}
```

And this is a `Product` page:

```
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <h1>{{$product->title}} <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1><br>
                <img style="height: 200px" src="{{$product->image}}"><br>
                <p>{!! $product->description !!}</p>
        <div class="bootstrap-wrapper">
            <a style="float: right; margin-top: -150px; margin-right: 300px; font-size: 24px"
               href="/prideti-i-krepseli/{{$product->id}}" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i> Pridėti į krepšelį</a><br>
            {{number_format($product->price, 2, '.', ',')}} EUR
        </div>
    </div>
```

So if I want to send some values from a form, how would I insert them in session ? Should I write post method code in `add` function ? Can you give me some example ? I want to make a form that will set a quantity for each item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel How to store extra data/value in session Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597273/laravel-how-to-store-extra-data-value-in-session-laravel)

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#basic-usage

Comment: @CarlosCarucce Okay, so I should just set empty field called "quantity" and then send it to session in my Controller ?

Comment: @CarlosCarucce Still how to add new value to my controller ?

Comment: Hey man a simple google search will get you useful results https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand you want to add array of values into session (shopping cart can be represented as array).

To store values in array and not as single session variable you need to change your

```
public function add(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->session()->push('cart', $id);
    flash()->success('Prekė sėkmingai pridėtą į krepšelį.');
    return redirect('/prekes');
}
```

with

```
public function add(Request $request, $id, $quantity)
{
    $product_from_db = Product::find($id);
    $product = [];
    $product['id'] = $id;
    //you can add all data you need like this etc...
    $product['name'] = $product_from_db->name;
    $product['quantity'] = $quantity;        
    $request->session()->push('cart', array_merge((array)Session::get('cart',[]), $product));    
    flash()->success('Prekė sėkmingai pridėtą į krepšelį.');
    return redirect('/prekes');
}
```

To receive data from session replace

```
public function show()
{    
    $products = session('cart');
    $products = Product::find($products);
    return view('cart.show', compact('products'));
}
```

with

```
public function show()
{    
    $products = session('cart');
    return view('cart.show', compact('products'));
}
```

And in your View you show that data like this

```
@if(Session::has('cart'))
    @foreach(Session::get('cart') as $item)
        {{$item['id']}}
        {{$item['name']}}
        {{$item['quantity']}}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I want to add product's quantity to session. It's a new value. And how do I do that ?

Comment: @labas GamePage visogero I have updated my answer to help you get your desired solution. Hope it helps

Comment: So now I need to make a form in my view with input named "quantity" to get the value ?

Comment: Updated answer again. Possible syntax errors and minor fixes need maybe. But just to show you whole picture of how to achieve what you want

Comment: How to add value to $quantity variable ? Post method ?

Comment: Same as you send id that you want to store to session, that's why function add got quantity as input param `public function add(Request $request, $id, $quantity)`

Comment: `$request->session()->push(array_merge((array)Session::get('cart',''), array($product)));` in this line I get error that says: Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Session\Store::push()

Comment: Edited answer again. My bad for minor error. Just replace that line with     `$request->session()->push('cart', array_merge((array)Session::get('cart',''), array($product))); `

Comment: Okay, now when I go to check my cart I get this error: `Trying to get property of non-object` in this line: @if(Session::has('cart'))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113767/discussion-between-kukec-and-labas-gamepage-visogero).

Comment: Are you using blade view template?