# How to share variables to all controllers and views in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.5 project where I would need to share some variables throughout all controllers and all views with the option to have some global defaults and then those defaults could be edited within the various controller methods, and in the end the views would show those updated variables.

For example:

```
$test = [1, 2, 3];
```

in `fooController.php` BarMethod I would say:

```
$test[] = 4;
```

Then the view file that is accompanied with that BarMethod would see `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

But if I said something else in `testController.php` BazMethod:

```
$test = array_merge($test, [100, 1000, 10000]);
```

Then my other view that belongs to this method would see `[1, 2, 3, 100, 1000, 10000]`.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks.

---

Okay, so to clarify: I am talking about multiple requests, the 1st request would go to `fooController`, the 2nd one to `testController`, the nth one to some `nthController`. In all cases there would be the initial `$test` variable with its default value, then all the requested methods in the controllers could alter the default initial variable and then send it to the view.

All this I can achieve for example by having the default values of `$test` set in a `baseController`, then update the values in either of the methods, but my real issue is that I need to specify the variable among the list of variables to send to the view in all methods.

So what I'd need is a way automatically send that updated `$test` variable to all views. I was looking at service providers, but it seemed to me that a service provider would do its job before editing the values, so the initial value would show up in the view, not the updated value.

I honestly don't think sessions could help in this situation.

Comment: Not really sharing between controllers as much as sharing in the session, right?  The typical reason you should reach two controller methods is through two different requests...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel How to store extra data/value in session Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597273/laravel-how-to-store-extra-data-value-in-session-laravel)

Comment: Have you tried this approach `$test = array_merge($test, [100, 1000, 10000]);`? Because $test will not be available here and it would give Undefined variable $test in `TestController.php`

Comment: I would use the session, check for the value in the controller and proceed.

Comment: [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Middleware to populate a Configuration variable, configuration is always available from all the framework.

```
public function handle()
{
    config(['myCustomConfig.email' => 'me@example.com']);
}

// index.blade.php

<div>{{ config('myCustomConfig.email') }} </div>
```

Saving the value on the config make it available from views, controllers or even models.

If you don't like to use config for that purpose, you can create a Service Class (not Service Provider), and declare it as a Singleton.

```
// app/Services/SharingService.php

namespace App\Services;

class SharingService {

    private $shared = [];

    public function share($name, $value)
    {
        $this->shared[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function get($name, $default = null)
    {
        if (isset($this->shared[$name])) {
            return $this->shared[$name];
        }

        return $default;
    }
}

// AppServiceProvider.php

$this->app()->singleton('shared', function() {

    $sharingService = new SharingService();

    $sharingService->share('email', 'me@example.com');
    // ☝️ you can set values here or in any place, since it's a public method

    return $sharingService;
});

// index.blade.php

<div>{{ app('shared')->get('email') }}</div> <!-- me@example.com -->

// any Controller or model

$email = app('shared')->get('email');
```

As you can see, the behaviour is like config, but with this approach you're preventing overriding some configurations on the fly by mistake. The code can be improved with checks and other methods, this was a quick example of how you can do it.

Comment: Yes, an After Middleware would be something I'm looking for, I'm almost certain, but without involving sessions. I just simply want to automatically pass variables from the controller actions to the views, without providing those variables explicitly in `return view('someviewfile', [ ... ])`.
The content of those variables will be different per controller action, that's why I can't use the service providers (at least I think so).

Comment: @csm you said `but without involving sessions`. You can't pass variables from request to request without storing something in database or in session. Lifecycle of PHP dies in each request.

Comment: There's some wording confusion here, I see now. By requests I meant two completely different users doing two requests to two completely different controllers and/or actions. E.g.:
User1 calling `/home/login`
User2 calling `/settings/edit`
Where `home` is the short for `HomeController` and `settings` points to `SettingsController`. Both these controllers would have the same variables that could have different values, e.g. different list of CSS files that should be automatically passed to the views, without needing to always pass the variable explicitly.
I hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @csm I'll edit the answer to match what you say in this last comment

Comment: Thank you, I think service classes are what I need in this case.

Answer (score 3):

First we have to create global.php file in config folder.

`config/global.php`, Then add the below code

```
return [
    'clientid' => '2',
    'code' => 'xyz
];
```

Access the global varibale like below

```
config('global.clientid')
```